# glewInit() and GLEW_ARB_xxx_ failure in client program

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glew

I wrote a DLL that initializes an OpenGL context using glew. Firstly I created a dummy window to create the appropriate context. Secondly, the final context and window are created.
`glewInit()` function call succeeded and some boolean variable such as `GLEW_ARB_texture_storage` are set to 1 (I have a video adapter compatible with opengl 3.3).

Note that

```
glewExperimental=GL_TRUE
```

though.

However, when I'm writing the client program using the DLL above, the same `GLEW_ARB_texture_storage` variable equals `GL_FALSE`.

Therefore, I'm wondering where `glewInit()` should be finally called ?
It seems that calling it from the DLL is not enough. Should I also call it from the client program side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually would not make a point of initializing GLEW from your dummy context. Consider manually loading the one or two extensions you need to create your final context by hand (e.g. `WGL_ARB_create_context` and `WGL_ARB_pixel_format`). You are not guaranteed to get the same ICD implementation on Windows when you create two different contexts. That is why GLEW MX was created.

Now, what I suspect is happening in your case is not actually that you are getting two different ICDs (that is extremely rare in the real-world), but actually that the first context you create is a compatibility profile and the second is a core profile.

GLEW initializes the variables such as `GLEW_ARB_texture_storage` using the extensions string, but in a core profile GLEW is not smart enough to parse that string the right way (multiple calls to `glGetStringi (...)`). This is why you have to use `GLEW_EXPERIMENTAL`.

`GLEW_EXPERIMNETAL` tells GLEW to try and load every function pointer for every extension it knows about without first parsing any extension string to check availability. That is a necessary evil in core profiles, but not in compatibility (because the old extension string mechanism is still valid in compatibility). Any part of GLEW that relies on parsing the extension string is not going to work correctly in a core profile.

Comment: Ok. Does it also explain why glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) returns a valid string when the dummy context is created and a NULL pointer when the final context is created ?

Comment: @Zyend: Yes, not only that. But it's also generating `GL_INVALID_ENUM` when you call it in the final context. Check `glGetError (...)` before and after calling it.

Comment: You're right Andon, the first created context is a compatibility profile and the second a core profile. Setting GLEW_EXPERIMENTAL to GL_TRUE fixes the issue in my library side.
However, in the client side program, I was unable to test GLEW_ARB_texture_storage for example. Whereas this variable = GL_TRUE in the DLL side. I changed my DLL into a static lib...and there it worked.

Comment: However, how is it possible that GLEW_EXT_direct_state_access equals FALSE although GL_EXT_direct_state_access is found in glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) ?

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote a DLL that initializes an OpenGL context using glew

That's not what *GLEW* does. GLEW does not initialize OpenGL contexts, GLEW loads OpenGL extension function addresses and initializes function pointers with them. You must call GLEW with an pre-existing OpenGL context being created and made current in the thread calling `glewInit()`.

Your program creates an OpenGL context somewhere and after that calls `glewInit()` apparently. And from the way you describe it, your DLL probably just calls `glewInit()` through the `DllMain` entry function, which gets called when the DLL is loaded, which is usually before when the processes `WinMain` or / `main` function are called, so a OpenGL context has not been created. You can create a OpenGL context in your DLL of course, but you have to ask yourself, if that makes sense to the user of the DLL.

Comment: Hello. In my DLL, I have of course created a respective window and a valid opengl context before calling glewInit().